RKJXT1F42001 Logic diagram
I'm looking into integrating an RKJXT1F42001  4-directional stick switch with encoder and center push function into a keyboard I am designing, but a little confused about the diagram. I want to make sure I understand it correctly.
From what I can tell, the center PUSH will always trigger when pointing in the directions of A B C or D because the PUSH-COM are connected.

My original thought was I could connect the COM with a diode to my ROW in my keyboard matrix, and then A B C D and PUSH to different columns so that they are all their own keys in my matrix. Or do vice versa with each A B C D and PUSH connected with diodes to rows, and COM on one column. However I don't think that will work now that I realize the PUSH-COM are connected. PUSH will always trigger right?

If this truly is the case where PUSH will always trigger when pointing in A B C or D directions, I'll either need to make logic gates in software, but I was also wondering if maybe I could go about this with hardware logic gates, i.e. diodes. Something like (centre + direction) = direction, and (centre + !direction) = centre.
